# Remove duplicates according to data in 2 columns by priority in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to remove duplicates in Excel by comparing 2 columns and by priority, meaning:

I have priority by category such as cat 1 > cat 2 > cat 3 > cat 4

And I want to match if some text that appears in column 2 and 4 matches any other row it will delete the row that has the lower category priority

Here is an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lobyp.png

Explanation of the image:
Orange cells should be deleted, blue ones should be kept.

**Update:**

What I am trying to achieve: I have a list of URLs in column B (Source URLs), another list of URLs in column C (which are target URLs of links), anchor text in column D, column A contains the data source to help me identify from where I pulled the data from. I just want to make sure that there aren't any duplicates between all data sources but maintaining a certain priority, which will prefer to delete duplicates from Category 2 if the exact source URL and anchor appear in Category 1 and etc.

Comment: The **Remove Duplicates** command is not working for you?

Comment: No it didn't, I have tried this solution: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/733727-removing-duplicate-on-priority-criteria.html

Problem is that this script is based only on one column instead of 2

Comment: Why didn't it? It seems a perfect solution.

Comment: The problem with this script is that it deletes duplicates based on the B column, and I need to delete duplicates based on text that appears in 2 columns, for example B and D.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask you about the sample script. I'm not a member there and I am not going to join just to see an example you pointed to that does not even work. I meant to ask you why **Remove Duplicates** does NOT work. It does exactly what you are describing faster and better than any other method I know of.

Comment: Indeed it will but it won't keep the priority that I want it to keep as I described above.

Comment: According to your sample data in the image you provided, it will keep the priority. **Remove Duplicates** always deletes from the bottom up. If your *actual* data is different you should have said so.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to keep suggesting this method like it's a favourite hobby of mine... but have you thought about using a "key" column? Create a column E with formula `= B1 & D1`. Then you can make another column with formula `= countif(E:E,E1)` or even better `= and(countif(E:E,E1) > 1, A1 <> "Category1")` this will give you a boolean column you can use to filter/delete.

Only issue is that method of countif gets really really slow for large spreadsheets... in which case use VBA with the same theory maybe

Comment: PS marking rows in this way, then sorting and deleting them all at once is a lot quicker than one by one if yer gonna use VBA

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but I get a `#name` error, am I doing something wrong? What I am trying to do is: I have a list of URLs in column B (Source URLs), another list of URLs in column C (which are target URLs of links), anchor text in column D, column A contains the data source to help me identify from where I pulled the data from.

I just want to make sure that there aren't any duplicates between all data sources but maintaining a certain priority, which will prefer to delete duplicates from Catergory 2 if the exact source URL and anchor appear in Category 1 and etc.

Comment: name error in the countif? Sorry was being a bit lazy/psudo, will update my answer: check the "edit" notes :)